# Aligning entries in a menubar

Tags: python, tkinter, menubar

I have three entries in a menubar which are automatically allocated on the left side. How can I ensure that the third entry (i.e. the entry 'Three') is always on the right side?

```
    self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
    self.menu.add_command(label="One", command=self.One)
    self.menu.add_command(label="Two", command=self.Two)
    self.menu.add_command(label=" "*70)
    self.menu.add_command(label="Three", command=self.Three)
    self.configure(menu=self.menu)
```

What I have done so far is to insert the command with a blank label and without the option command. It works, but that is not a flexible solution. As far as I found out there does not seem to exist something like an alignment option.
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ensure that the third entry (i.e. the entry 'Three') is always on the right side?

You can't. tkinter doesn't support any options for putting menu items on the right except in one very rare circumstance. Specifically, if you are an X11-based system, you have motif compatibility turned on, and the internal path to the menu is .menubar.help.